# Querying by Keys with LogicBlox

Tags: logicblox, logiql

If I have two predicates (not functional):

```
addblock 'city(city_dim_id) -> int(city_dim_id).'
addblock 'city_name[city_dim_id] = name -> int(city_dim_id), string(name).'
```

I can add facts:

```
exec '+city(1).'
exec '+city_name[0] = "N/A".'
exec '+city_name[1] = "Chicago".'
```

These are then queries of facts in the predicates:

```
query '_(city_name) <- city_name(city_name, _).'
query '_(city_name) <- city_name(_, city_name).'
query '_(city_dim_id, city_name) <- city_name(city_dim_id, city_name).'
```

My question is how do I make a query to show 
1. what are the city_dim_id in both tables,
2. return city_dim_id and city_name, but only where city_dim_id present in both tables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm struggling to understand the question.
The following will return the city_dim_id's that have the same city_name.

```
_(c1, c2) <-
    city(c1),
    city(c2),
    city_name[c1] = city_name[c2],
    c1 != c2.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If by ' city_dim_id in both tables ' you mean 'city_dim_id which are in both tables' then you want

   ```
   _(id) <-city(id), city_name[id] = _.
   ```

if on the other hand you want the id who are in either table, you need to replace the conjunction by a disjunction.

```
_(id) <- city(id); city_name[id] = _.
```

2. I think you want

   ```
   _(id,name) <- city(id), city_name[id] = name.
   ```

*note: if you use the square bracket syntax `city_name[id] = name` then the predicate WILL be functional*